# How to point a domain name to a subfolder

Tags: domains, apache, web-development, subdomain, subdirectory

I have a working website:

`https://www.example.com`

It is a bit old, and now I want to make a new website.   I don't want to make it on localhost but directly on the web.

I was thinking to make the website on

`https://2021.example.com`

or on `https://www.example.com/2021/`

But before I set things up, is this the best way?   When the website is good and it is time to going live.   How do I point it with my domain name to the subfolder `/2021/`

I my own dedicated server with a hosting provider.  It is running Linux, Apache, Joomla, and a control panel written by by the hosting provider (Combell).

I want to leave the old site running so  that I can use the old and new sites in A/B tests.

Answer (score 2):

Make a subdomain e.g. dev.example.com, and create your new site in that space.

Then when it is finished, simply move all the files to the directory containing your old site.  Once you have done that you can repeat the process for other subdomains, but in their own directory...but if they are new subdomains, likely no one knows they exist, so just build them in their final place.

I am not sure how Joomla works, but watch out for absolute links e.g. `/home/user/public_html/css/filename`, compared to relative links e.g. `/css/filename` when moving files.

Comment: Since Combell has created its own custom control panel, you'll have to ask them how you would use it to create a subdomain.   I can't find any documentation about how you would do so in their knowledge base.   They do have a page for creating subdomains using Plesk: https://www.combell.com/en/help/kb/how-can-i-add-a-subdomain-with-plesk/